# Firestore Import database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I trying to set up a development environment from an existent project on Firebase, we are currently using Firestore as a database. I've successfully exported the Firestore data from one project to another but I can't figure out a way of importing the data, it keeps saying

```
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.import) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

I've tried adding the `[SOURCE_PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as a Storage admin on the bucked but got no success, also tried adding all possible permissions and accessing through the cli the services accounts.

Which permissions do I need in order to import this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a source_project and a new dev_project, and you're trying to run `gcloud firestore import` for your dev_project. Some things to check:

Make sure `gcloud` is connected to your dev_project:

`gcloud config set project DEV_PROJECT_ID`

From the error, it sounds like the account you're using with `gcloud` doesn't have permission to run `gcloud firestore import` for your dev_project. Make sure your user account is a project owner or has the `datastore.owner` role for your dev_project.

For the bucket permissions, it's the `[DEV_PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account that needs access to the bucket with the data files.

Also see [docs for moving Firestore data between projects](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/move-data).